# Couldn't Debug the Complete Code to Create the Window

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging

As what have said on [Creating a Window (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> *“Congratulations, you've created a window! Right now, the window does
>   not contain any content or interact with the user.”*

But I couldn't debug the complete code which was mentioned to create the window. This is the *main.cpp* source:

```
#include <windows.h>

// Register the window class.
const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Sample Window Class";

WNDCLASS wc = { };

wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

RegisterClass(&wc);

// Create the window.

HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    0,                              // Optional window styles.
    CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
    L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

    // Size and position
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

    NULL,       // Parent window    
    NULL,       // Menu
    hInstance,  // Instance handle
    NULL        // Additional application data
    );

if (hwnd == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}

ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
```

I'm using *Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop*. Starting with **New Project**, choosing **Visual C++**, **Empty Project**. I tried even to `#include <iostream>` without and with `using namespace std;` hoping for a little bit.. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem.

Debugging gets many errors. One of the suspecting codes is the *"wc"*:

```
wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

RegisterClass(&wc);
```

Sorry for this, *(I think, this is simple,)* for I'm just beginning..

Comment: Do you have a [WinMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function?

Comment: Your code should be placed in function, probably `main`. And you should define `WindowProc`. And you should'nt try any magic like ' I tried even to `#include <iostream>` without and with using namespace std;', but rather read some book.

Comment: The code you've shown cannot be compiled. It's too early to speak about debugging. Almost all this code (excluding #include) must be inside some function, e.g. WinMain.

Comment: Actually you can find the working code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it's from your first link even.

Comment: @Dirk Yeah, the code must be inside some function..

Answer (score 2):

> choosing Visual C++, Empty Project

Just don't choose that.  Choose Win32 Project instead.  You get precooked code that implements a minimum native Windows project with everything set correctly.  Extend it and make it do something useful.

Once you learn more about this kind of programming and have read Petzold's "Programming Windows" three times, you'll be able to tackle writing a program from scratch.  Only then select the guru setting and start with the "Empty Project" project template.  Trying to do it the other way around is inevitably very disappointing, you can't learn *everything* you need to do correctly in one session.

Comment: Thanks for answering.. I only choose Visual C++, Empty Project to help myself understand what I'm learning. *(Of course I know how to include a header, I just want to study it one by one.)* And once I learn and ready to develop a program, I'll choose Win32 Project.

Comment: I'll repeat what I stated in the answer, you are doing it the wrong way around.  Once you learned how this all fits together, you don't need that Win32 Project template anymore.  Tackle one problem at a time.  Learn how to write correct code first, the template is there to avoid having to learn how to get two hundred compiler and linker settings right the first time.

Comment: Agreed.. Your point when it's come to web developing, is such like, once you learned how to design a website, you don't need an instant web template. But I just want to test all the tutorials on [Learn to Program for Windows in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/ff381399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: to learn, create both kind of projects and diff the resulting files